# Saving versions of projects for testing concepts in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've been having this problem with visual studio that I cannot seem to find a simple answer to. I would like to be able to save out versions of my visual studio project so that I can test a concept I have in mind that may dramatically change my code and if I do not like the outcome, I would like to be able to load up a older (previous) version of my project. Every googled answer I have found for this problem has been some kind of big professional development version control software. Its crazy to me that there is not a simpler way. I suppose I could copy and paste my project dir each time I want to save a "version" and just rename it, but this seems rather archaic. I use many graphic applications that simply have a "save as with new version" feature and I can easelly load and version I have saved.

any advice would be amazingly helpful.

thank you!!!

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help)it will be useful to lift your content quality up

Comment: Version control is not crazy or big. It's an important tool for every developer.

Answer (score 2):

Just use git!
https://git-for-windows.github.io/

It is a very simple light weight version control system, that will do everything you are asking for. It is free, and should only take a few minutes to set up.